# Get a local node identity / peer id

Tags: key, libp2p

I need to know my node's peer identity to use it as a boot node. Didn't start the node with `--node-key`. Also, the node has been running for so long that I can no longer access the startup logs containing `2021-03-10 17:34:27   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWEyopp...`. Is there any other way to obtain my node's peer identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can query the local peerId through an rpc call. For example using polkadotjs

[image: Example screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the command line...

```
curl -sS -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "system_localPeerId"}' http://localhost:${port}/
```

Replace `${port}` with your `--ws-port` value.