# How to obtain a peer address?

Tags: peers, bootnode

In older versions of the Substrate node template, the node would print some helpful information on startup. For example it would print the ports being used for the websocket and p2p endpoints. It would also print the Peer Id.

As of today ((latest commit)[https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/4ea490ef8ee7cde7668c56dc548e72ee8695297b]) it no longer prints this information. How can I get a node's Peer id to use as a bootnode?

Answer (score 3):

For Polkadot Apps, just like what @andresvsm mentioned.

For CLI, just:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9933 -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"system_localPeerId","params":[],"id":1}'
```

And if you want to interact with Rust, try [this](https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/blob/0d0e2c4e8dac0d76654a0a3130e74c1314ca37ba/substrate-minimal/subrpcer/src/system.rs#L44-L47).

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed that, and I'm not sure if its a bug or they've added some additional flags for that, but I guess you can query a node PeerId using RPC calls or interacting via the Polkadot JS App like this [Get a local node identity / peer id](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/get-a-local-node-identity-peer-id/2987#2987)