# How can i fetch the node identity from cli?

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, bootnode

How we can fetch the node identity(local node identity in snapshort) after running the node i would need it so that i can make process automatic to start the second node by using that node key

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain a peer address?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/how-to-obtain-a-peer-address)

Comment: And https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/how-to-obtain-a-peer-address.

Comment: Please use the search first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl command from cli to get the node identity using the following command:

`curl -sS -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "system_localPeerId"}' http://localhost:9933/`

Just replace the rpc url if you have hosted your node somewhere or if accessing the node locally than the above command is good to go.

Comment: Good answer. But please don't answer the duplicate question. And there were already a lot of similar questions like this.